# How to give control over keyboard back to X server after Alt + SysRq + R trick

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout, sysrq

Situation: an application freezes the X server and no keyboard input works. So I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to take the keyboard out of raw mode (make the kernel take control of the keyboard away from the X server). I can then type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, kill the bad processes, and everything works again. So far so good.

But the keyboard is still in the hands of the kernel, making <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> shortcuts for Decr_Console/Incr_Console. This is annoying, and I want to give control over the keyboard back to the X server.

I have tried typing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> again, this does not switch things back. I have also tried the command `kbd_mode -u`, but nothing changes.

Any advice?

Answer (score 10):

```
sudo kbd_mode -s -C /dev/tty7
```

Eventually you have to change the console path, if your X server is running on a different virtual terminal.

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19296/recovering-from-sys-rq-r